# Would it possible that postgres Write-Ahead Log DOUBLE RE-APPLY?

Tags: postgresql, wal

I found quote here

> PostgreSQL is one of the databases relying on write-ahead log (WAL) –
>   all changes are written to a log (a stream of changes) first, and only
>   then to the data files. That provides durability, because in case of a
>   crash the database may use WAL to perform recovery – read the changes
>   from WAL and re-apply them on data files.

from this article https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/basics-of-tuning-checkpoints/

Let say there is WAL file keep following query

`UPDATE page SET view_count = view_count + 1;`

I can imagine the case that, postgres already apply this WAL to DB
but it crash right after it apply.

DB doesn't update latest WAL position NOR delete WAL log file yet.

When DB is up, it will do recovery and reapply this WAL again, isn't it?
And would this final value in database become `view_count + 2` ?

Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such situation called *Partial Page Write*. PostgreSQL has configuration option to prevent protect against this problem [`full_page_writes`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-FULL-PAGE-WRITES). It's enabled by default:

> When this parameter is on, the PostgreSQL server writes the entire content of each disk page to WAL during the first modification of that page after a checkpoint. This is needed because a page write that is in process during an operating system crash might be only partially completed, leading to an on-disk page that contains a mix of old and new data.

Changes replayed by restoring page copy instead of redoing the update.

Comment: That make sense, Thanks a lot!

Comment: i have one more question. If it update data for the entire table that is really huge (e.g. table size 2gb). Would `full_page_writes` limit this operation since memory size is not high enough?

Comment: No, `full_page_writes` has no limits for the number of written pages. Each table in Postgre is stored as an array of a fixed size [pages](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-page-layout.html). Particular row can be stored in any page. This page are written to WAL on first modification. So if the entire table (each row) is modified all corresponding pages will be written to WAL.